"Shining Composer"
The answer to this simple puzzle is a name. Explain your reasoning.
WEAK C: 223357
STRONG C: 572235

2233575722---35


Who Am I?

I noticed all the numbers were prime. Is this relevant (your username sounds like "prime number")?

the numbers go up to 7, which might correspond to piano keys. "weak" and "strong" c = weak and strong chords? And the title hints that the answer may be a composer name. The string could be a familiar melody with the dashes as rests

@fencer22 Along that train of thought, I thought maybe this had something to do with "sea to shining sea" (from America the Beautiful), though this particular train has not left the station

@Lucenaposition Yes, that's relevant. Nothing to do with me though

To answer the two other comments, it has nothing to do with music

The name we're looking for is

 Goldbach.

The phrases "Weak C" and "Strong C" in the text block refer to

 The weak and strong Goldbach conjectures. The weak version states that every odd number over 5 can be expressed as the sum of three primes, and the strong version says every even number over 2 can be written as the sum of two primes.

This explains the numbers that appear in the puzzle, because

 If we convert the letters of GOLDBACH to numbers (A is 1, B is 2 and so on), we get 7, 15, 12, 4, 2, 1, 3, 8. The weak version applies to 7 and 15, giving the representations 2+2+3 and 3+5+7, which are the numbers that appear next to "WEAK C". The strong version applies to 12, 4, 8 whose respective representations are 5+7, 2+2, and 3+5 — the numbers next to "STRONG C". The last line combines all of these into a single string, with blank spaces corresponding to 2, 1, 3 (B,A,C) since neither version of the Goldbach conjecture applies to these numbers.

Lastly, the title

 is a charade for Goldbach: "shining" giving "gold" and "composer" giving "Bach".


This is ofc correct, well done!
